# After reviving my vampire companion, how do I get his equipment back?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

Long story short, Aerie has been kidnapped by Bodhi and turned into a vampire, so I had to kill and revive her. When she disappeared, she was wearing the Robe of Vecna and carrying the Bag of Holding with most of my goodies, but when I revive her, her inventory is empty. How can I get my things back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before killing and reviving Aerie, you should check the spot at the graveyard where you first meet Bodhi. Alternatively don't give her all those items in the first place.